# simple dapp with React "issues with solidity"

Tags: solidity, truffle, react

i am trying to build a simple app (will improve once i get the simple one to work)I created a new Reactapp, added both the contracts and migrations directories and i use ganache and metamaks.
I have truffle installed. and i can successfully compile and migrate my contact on ganache

The Dapp has an input field that takes a string and save in bolckchain and then fetch it back and diplay that on screen.

I get an error form this part.

```
import SimpleStorageContract from '../build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json'
```

/src/App.js

> Module not found: You attempted to import ../build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

And if i move build/contracts directory into src i get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

[**full code**:](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16_c7_O9S6awa5L7drETU5m6gvT1vwhh-)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
//import SimpleStorageContract from '../build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json'
import SimpleStorageContract from './build/contracts/SimpleStorage.json'
import getWeb3 from './utils/getWeb3'
import truffleContract from "truffle-contract";
class App extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            account: null,
            web3: null,
            firstName:null,
            fName:null,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    getWeb3.then(results => {
    this.setState({ web3: results.web3

    })

        this.instantiateContract()
    })
        .catch(() => {
    console.log('Error finding web3.')
        })
    }

    instantiateContract() {
    /*
     * SMART CONTRACT EXAMPLE
     *
     * Normally these functions would be called in the context of a
     * state management library, but for convenience I've placed them here.
     */

    const contract = require(truffleContract)
    const simpleStorage = contract(SimpleStorageContract)
    simpleStorage.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)

    // Get accounts.
    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        simpleStorage.deployed().then((instance) => {
            this.simpleStorageInstance = instance;
            this.setState({ account: accounts[0] });
            // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
            return this.simpleStorageInstance.get.call(accounts[0])
        })
    })
}
      handleSubmit = ()=> {

          const response = this.simpleStorageInstance.get().call();
          this.setState({fName: response.c[0]});
      }






    handleChange = (event)=> {
        const value = event.target.value;

        this.simpleStorageInstance.set(value , {from: this.state.account}).then((r) => {
            return this.setState({ firstName: value })
    })
    }


    render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">

              <div>
                  <form onSubmit= {this.handleSubmit}>
                  <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                  <input type="submit"/>

              </form></div>
            <p>{this.state.firstName}</p>
            <p>{this.state.fName}</p>
        </p>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

SimpleStorage.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract SimpleStorage {
    string firstName;

    function set(string x) public {
        firstName = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (string) {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that it's not correct way to import the smart contract into an dApp. The correct way should be as below code snippet

```
    let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(WEB3.HTTP))

    const SimpleStorage = web3.eth.contract(WEB3.ABI)
    const contract = SimpleStorage(WEB3.ADDRESS_CONTRACT)
```

So you need to declare three constant

1. `WEB3.HTTP` is the http end-point of your node, E.x: `http://localhost:8545`
2. `WEB3.ABI` smart contract abi
3. `WEB3.ADDRESS_CONTRACT` smart contract address

Hope this help!

Comment: Note that WEB3.ABI in this example is the JSON you were trying to import in the original question, so I don't think it solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that create-react-app has a prohibition on importing anything outside the `src/` directory.

You can get around it by doing an `eject` but you probably don't want that because afterward you can't take advantage of updates to the create-react-app scripts. More on that here if you want to try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115058/203704

The approach I took was to reconfigure Truffle to compile the scripts to `src/abi` directory instead of the default `build/contracts`. To do that, (according to [the docs](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#contracts_build_directory)) you only have to add a **contracts_build_directory** entry in your `truffle.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    contracts_build_directory: "./src/abi",
    networks: {...}
};
```

However, I found this to have inconsistent behavior depending upon whether I ran `compile` before `migrate` or just let `migrate -reset` recompile and migrate, the upshot of which was that it would complain about not finding the `src/abi` folder.

I discovered that [others had seen this same problem](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/862#issuecomment-377952233) and the workaround was this:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "/src/abi"),
    networks: {...}
    }
};
```

Comment: this is working for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had problem with my import syntax.
I was doing it like,
`import MyStringStore from "../../contracts/MyStringStore.json";`
While the correct import was `import MyStringStore from "../contracts/MyStringStore.json";` 
 Because the contracts folder was outside of current directory, i.e. drizzle. And I didn't notice that kept searching for days and weeks but to no avail. I though the problem would be something big that I'm missing. This morning I was just looking at my code with a kind of hopeless mind, and I looked upon this import how the contract is being imported, and Thank GOD there it is. Gotcha!