# Running Migrate in Truffle does not work

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, ganache-cli

I have been using Remix for developing my dapp but decided I should use Truffle to make things a little more robust and professional. I have truffle and ganache installed. I run

```
truffle migrate
```

and get the following results:

[image]

The Ganache output looks like this:

[image]

The migration script looks like:

```
var Collateral = artifacts.require('Collateral');

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Collateral);
};
```

This contract is one of many contracts in the file DirectLending.SOL which is stored in the contracts directory.

My understanding of truffle migrate is that so long as the contract file is in the contracts directory, it will be compiled and the contract should be findable by truffle.

I also tried to create a single file collateral.sol with just the Collateral contract in it and that also did not work.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Phil

Comment: Thanks Alberto. I changed the code as you suggested but nothing changes and I still get the message "Could not find artifacts for Collateral from any sources". Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment. Have you tried `truffle migrate --reset`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it still does not work. What else could be wrong?

Comment: It appears to think it has compiled the contracts. The stage where it's bombing is where it would take the compiled contracts and deploy them. Question is where are the contracts being output to? Search your project for Collateral.json. I don't know how your project has been set up, but I ran into an issue with it where I had to configure a new output folder for contracts so react-create-app could build an app that has access to the contract abi. In case it helps: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/60575/44463

Comment: Another thought: If the Collateral contract is extended (with is) by another contract in the system, then there won't be a separate file for it in the output. When you put Collateral into its own file, what was the error? Does it extend another contract? It would be useful to know the contract hierarchy (if there is one).

Comment: I think the problem is that the JSON is not being created. I tried recompiling but it does not do anything. I am sure it is a stupid mistake but I am really struggling here! So far as I understand ALL contracts in the contracts directory should be compiled but apart from migrations.sol no other contracts are compiled. Thanks for your advice so far...

Comment: In the `contracts` directory you need to have the `.sol` files, so that truffle can compile them and migrate. `.json` files will be generated in the `build` folder.

Comment: @alberto That is what I have, but the .json for all .sol files are not being created for some reason...

Comment: @PhilipRutovitz It is prefereble to use a contract per file. Delete `build/` directory and force truffle to recompile all the contracts `truffle compile --all`.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for the advice. I tried what you suggested. Truffle still only compiles Migrations.sol even though there are 2 other files in the contracts directory... This is really frustrating!

Comment: @PhilipRutovitz Do the others files have `.sol` extension? Did you try to compile in another computer/virtual machine with Linux? Sometimes the Windows builds are broken, another option is to try upgrade/downgrade to another version of Truffle.

Comment: @Ismael yes they all have .sol extensions.